# Remove DataGridView cells containing duplicate values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My DataGridView looks like this:

[image: Sample screenshot]

How to clear the text of duplicate cells in the DataGridView Rows?

I tried below but it's clearing all values of `Cells[0]`.

```
string duplicateValue = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == duplicateValue)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = duplicateValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) as follows:

```
var valuesFound = new HashSet<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string cellText = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    // Attempt to add the value to the HashSet. If it fails, then it's a duplicate.
    if (!valuesFound.Add(cellText))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer LINQ, you could do something like this:

```
var duplicateCells = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => r.Cells[0])
    .GroupBy(c => c.Value.ToString())
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .ToList();

duplicateCells.ForEach(c => c.Value = string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

> How to clear the text of duplicate cells in the DataGridView Rows?

Apparent you consider some products to be the same. Alas you forgot to say when two products are equal. Is Product [Apple, UK, 1] equal to [Apple, UK, 2]? And if so, which one do you want to show?

Or do you want to show the sum: [Apple, UK, 3]?

And what about: [Apple, Ireland, 1]? Is that the same as [Apple, UK, 1]?

Clearly you need a method that says: this product equals that product, but that one is a different product.

For this we'll have to create an equality comparer.

```
class Product
{
    public Name {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    ...
}

IEqualityComparer<Product> productComparer = ... // TODO: implement
```

Once you've got this, you can get rid of duplicates:

```
IEnumerable<Product> productsWithDuplicates = ...
IEnumerable<Product> noDuplicates = productsWithDuplicates.Distinct(productComparer);
```

Or if you want to combine [Apple, UK, 1] and [Apple, UK, 2] to show the sum [Apple, UK, 3], use groupBy to make groups:

```
IEnumerable<Product> productsToDisplay = productsWithDuplicates
    .GroupBy(product => new {product.Name, product.Country}

    (key, productsWithThisKey) => new Product
    {
        Name = key.Name,
        Country = key.Country,
        Quantity = productWithThisKey.Select(product => product.Quantity).Sum(),
    },

    productComparer);
```

So the solution depends on when two products are equal, and what you want to show if you've found equal produts.

### Equality Comparer for Products

```
class ProductComparer : EqualityComparer<Product>()
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<Product> NameCountry {get;} = new ProductComparer();

    public override bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        if (x == null) return y == null; // true if both null, false if x null, but y not
        if (y == null) return false;     // because x not null
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) return true;

        // define equality, for instance:
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Country == y.Country;
    }
```

If you want case insensitive, add a property:

```
private static IEqualityComparer<string> NameComparer {get; } = StringComparer.InvariantIgnoreCase;
private static IEqualityComparer<string> CountryComparer {get;} = ...
```

And in Equals:

```
return NameComparer.Equals(x.Name, y.Name)
    && CountryComparer.Equals(x.Country, y.Country);
```

Now if you later decide that you want to be case sensitive when comparing Countries, or maybe want to use the current culture, you'll only have to change this on one location.

The use of the comparers, makes changing easier, but also your code: you don't have to check for null names and countries, that is handled by the comparers.

GetHashCode: only requirement: if x equals y, return same GetHashCode. if not equal, you are free to return whatever you want, but it is more efficient if you return different hashcode.

```
public override int GetHashCode(Product product)
{
    if (product == null) return 47855249; // just a number

    return NameComparer.GetHashCode(product.Name)
         ^ CountryComparer.GetHashCode(product.Country);
}
```

### There's room for improvement

It is usually not a good idea to intertwine your model with the view of your model. If in future you want to change how your data is displayed, for instance you want to show it in a ListBox, or in a Graph, you'll have to change a lot.

Besides, if you have separated your model from the way that it is displayed, it will be a lot easier to unit test your model. To test your view, you won't need your original data, you can test with edge conditions, like an empty datagridview,

First of all, you need a method to fetch the products from your model:

```
private IEnumerable<Productm> FetchProducts(...) {...}
```

So now you have a unit testable method that fetches the products. The nice thing is that you even hid where you get this information from: it can be from a database, or an XML file, or even from the internet: your Form doesn't know, and doesn't have to know. Totally designed for change.

Using visual studio designer you have defined columns. Every column shows exactly the value of one property. Which property the column shows is defined in property [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname)

```
columnName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
columnCountry.DatapropertyName =  nameof(Product.Country);
...
```

To show the fetched Products, use property [DataGridView.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource). If you assign a `List<Product>`, then changes that the operator makes (add / remove rows, change cells) are not reflected in the List. If you want to automatically update the changes that the operator made, use a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1)

```
public BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.datagridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.datagridView1.DataSource = value;
}

private IEqualityComparer<Product> ProductComparer {get;} = ProductComparer.NameCountry;

public void InitProductDisplay()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> productsToDisplay = this.FetchProducts()
        .Distinct(productComparer);

        // or if you want to show the totals: use the GroupBy described above

    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(productsToDisplay.ToList());
}
```

Nice! If you don't want to compare on NameCountry, but differently, or if you want to Compare using current culture, if you want to show the totals of the quantity, or even if you want to show it in a graph instead of a table: there is only one place you need to change.

Now every change that the operator makes: add / remove / change is reflected in your BindingList, even if the rows are sorted.

For instance, if the operator indicates that he finished editing by clicking a button:

```
private void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    var displayedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts;
    // find out which products are added / removed / changed
    this.ProcessEditedProducts(displayedProducts);
}
```

If you need to do something with selected rows, consider to add the follwing:

```
private Product CurrentProduct => (Product)(this.datagridView1.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem);

private IEnumerable<Product> SelectedProducts = this.datagridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewrow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<Product>();
```